# I can not solve this "NullPointerException"

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

i am trying to do access the database table records using swing event handling but after pressing the button it is showing exception. i dont know what is going wrong. here is my code:

```
private void DisplayAllButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.Act ionEvent evt) {

    try { 

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM OCCUPANTS";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL ); //line no 264

        while( rs.next( )) {
            int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
            String id=Integer.toString(id_col);
            String room =rs.getString("ROOM");
            String occupant = rs.getString("OCCUPANT");

            DisplayArea.setText( id + " " + room + " " + occupant);
        }
   } 
   catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
   }
}
```

**Fallowing is the exception:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at wumpus.WumpusGUI.DisplayAllButtonActionPerformed(W umpusGUI.java:264)
at wumpus.WumpusGUI.access$300(WumpusGUI.java:16)
at wumpus.WumpusGUI$4.actionPerformed(WumpusGUI.java: 164)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Abs tractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed (AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed (DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultB uttonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseRe leased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.jav a:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponen t.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:627 0)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:222 9)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.jav a:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.jav a:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:46 87)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent( Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(C ontainer.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Conta iner.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.jav a:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719 )
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:46 87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.j ava:703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102 )
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPri vilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPri vilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPri vilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java: 673)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilter s(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(E ventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarch y(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispa tchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispa tchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThre ad.java:97)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 28 seconds)
```

Here is the globally initialization of `stmt`

```
public class WumpusGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    /**
     * Creates new form WumpusGUI
     */
    public WumpusGUI() {
        initComponents();
        DBConnect();
    }

    public void DBConnect() {
        try {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/occupants";
            String uName = "ravi";
            String uPass= "ravi";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        }  
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is "stmt" and where is declared/initialised?

Comment: can you show line 264 in WumpusGUI.java

Comment: @Nirmal-thInkbeYond- very first code on 4th line i have mentioned by commenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you haven't shown where `stmt` is being declared, but it sounds like it's probably null. Where were you *expecting* it to be set to a non-null value?

Two points about this:

- You should be using a separate `PreparedStatement` each time you execute a query
- You shouldn't be performing database access in a UI thread anyway

(Additionally, your method name violates Java naming conventions.)

EDIT: From your comments, you've got:

```
public class WumpusGUI ... {
    Statement stmt;

    public void DBConnect() {
        ...
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ...
    }
}
```

That line of your method is declaring a new *local* variable - it isn't assigning a value to the *instance* variable, so the instance variable remains null.

The smallest "fix" would be to change that line to just:

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
```

... but as I said above, that wouldn't be the *right* fix. Ideally you should get *all* of this database code out of your GUI class to start with, but *at least* you should be creating a new statement each time you want to execute it. (And then closing it in a finally block.)

EDIT: Additionally, if you get an exception in the method, you're just printing it out and continuing merrily... so your `stmt` variable would *still* be null. *Don't* catch `Exception` in general, and *don't* catch exceptions that you really can't continue after.

Comment: i have globally declared 'stmt': 'public class WumpusGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    /**
     * Creates new form WumpusGUI
     */
    public WumpusGUI() {
        initComponents();
        DBConnect();
    }
public void DBConnect() {
try {
            
        
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/occupants";
        String uName = "ravi";
        String uPass= "ravi";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        
            }'

Comment: @raviahuja Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add this code.

Comment: @jon  : i have edited the code now please have a look. thanks

Comment: @raviahuja: I've edited my answer - I'd misread it as being in the constructor, but you've got the same problem in your (badly named) `DBConnect` method.

Comment: @jon: i changed that name now but still its same problem

Comment: @raviahuja: Changing the name of the method clearly isn't going to solve the problem. If it's still null, then maybe the method threw an exception when you called it. (That's another problem - your exception "handling" is poor.)

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, Greetings! I am little confused about the correct usage of Exception handling. i read your Edit statement, So i am curious get more resolution about the correct and best usage of exception handling.. can you suggest me some your article or some any relevant matter.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple: `stmt` hasn't been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Your stamt variable might have been initialized globally with null, but you would have failed to assign the value which you have to acquire from connection. Checkout your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the DBConnect method to initialise the stmt variable beofre using it.